# Logical operators in java (using Validation with Struts 1)

Tags: java, operators, struts-1, logical-operators

I'm confused about working with logical operators in java. I'm using struts 1 for fields  validations . Here is my code:

```
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

if(StringUtils.isBlank(getCode()) || StringUtils.isBlank(getNewCode())){
            errors.add("code", new  ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));
            errors.add("codeNew", new ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));

        }
```

if the field 'code' is not empty and the field 'newCode' is empty , the error message of the field 'code' appears (even if it's not empty), the same thing with the field 'newCode' . I want to know if there is some solution about avoiding the combination of the operator OR.(true || false)

This is what I'm searching for: (0=false 1=true)

```
0 || 0 => 0
1 || 0 => 0
0 || 1 => 0
1 || 1 => 1
```

Comment: Well, your code says that if the condition is true (the whole thing), then add two messages.  Computers are pretty dumb.  They don't read minds.  So it doesn't know that you meant "add the first message only if it's appropriate", and "add the second message only if appropriate".  You tell it to do both, it does both.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. I will edit my post more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with this technology but from
logical standpoint this makes more sense to me.

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(getCode())){
    errors.add("code", new  ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));
}

if(StringUtils.isBlank(getNewCode())){
    errors.add("codeNew", new ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));
}
```

Not sure if that's what you need, just guessing.

Comment: Yes thank you but I know that I can do that, I just prefer to find another solution ( because I have other IF)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution even if it's not totaly logical its works: (just adding the AND)

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(getCode()) && StringUtils.isBlank(getNewCode())){            errors.add("code", new ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));           errors.add("codeNew", new ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));        }
```

and the second one for this problem as peter.petrov suggested me :

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(getCode())){
    errors.add("code", new  ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));
}

if(StringUtils.isBlank(getNewCode())){
    errors.add("codeNew", new ActionMessage("error.codeMode.required"));
}
```

If someone has another solution that will be more helpfull for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "other solution". If you put `||` then both errors will be added if only one field is empty. If you put `&&` then both errors will be added when both fields are emtpy, but if only one is empty then nothing's gonna be added (which is also not what you want).

Only solution is what peter.petrov suggested

Comment: Yes I know but it's working because 'code' and 'codeNew', each one of these fields are in different pages (so even if two error messages are added only one are displayed in the page ) but I prefer to use the solution of peter.petrov even if it's not a better solution